# Does my rear tubular tire need to be replaced?

Tags: road-bike, tire, tubular

Does my rear tubular tire need to be replaced? It still holds air but I am concerned about my ride safety

[image]

Comment: That looks like some really hard emergency braking!

Comment: Yeah, it was a skid. I was doing some trenching. Not happy about it :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It needs to be replaced.

When the rubber tread is worn so far down the carcass is showing the tire is dangerous. The fabric carcass cannot provide grip like the rubber can so you risk losing grip in a corner and wiping out.

Comment: Thanks! Will replace :)

Comment: Concur.  I'm impressed that you managed to wear out a tubular, mine die with punctures well before they wear out.    When you remove this one, try to take it off in one piece and possibly save it as a last-resort spare.  Can't just swap in a tube when out on a ride.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do.